# Ignite On Spark: Error trying to save spark data frame to Ignite

Tags: apache-spark, ignite, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use ignite on top of spark and running some tests to see if it is useful for our specific use case. Able to start up the Ignite node using below code. Any help is much appreciated. This code works fine on my local machine. Running into error when running on spark cluser. Also all of this code is being executed using Zeppelin.

```
import org.apache.ignite.{Ignite, IgniteCache, Ignition}
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration
import org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteDataFrameSettings._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}

val configPath = "/mnt/yarn/data/example-ignite.xml"
val cacheName = "KiCache"

val ignite = Ignition.start(configPath)
val ccfg = new CacheConfiguration[Any, Any](cacheName).setSqlSchema("PUBLIC")

  //ccfg.setSqlEscapeAll(true)

val cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(ccfg)
```

After this while trying to save spark data frame as ignite table, running into an error

```
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite
import org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.SqlFieldsQuery
import org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteDataFrameSettings._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
//val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sc, configPath)
df.write.format(FORMAT_IGNITE).option(OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, 
configPath).option(OPTION_TABLE, 
"Test").option(OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS, 
"mtAccountNumber").option(OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS, 
"template=replicated").save()
```

Error:

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.componentException(IgniteComponentType.java:320)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create0(IgniteComponentType.java:296)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create(IgniteComponentType.java:207)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:742)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:783)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfiguration(IgnitionEx.java:823)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider$$anonfun$configProvider$1$1.apply(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:216)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider$$anonfun$configProvider$1$1.apply(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:213)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.Once.apply(IgniteContext.scala:222)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext.ignite(IgniteContext.scala:144)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext.<init>(IgniteContext.scala:63)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext$.apply(IgniteContext.scala:192)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider.igniteContext(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:236)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.IgniteRelationProvider.createRelation(IgniteRelationProvider.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
  ... 51 elided
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create0(IgniteComponentType.java:282)
  ... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 84 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the `ignite-spring` package. Here is the example for Spark shell: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/testing-integration-with-spark-shell#section-working-with-spark-shell

Comment: Thanks for reply. ignite-spring is loaded and i can see it in logs. we are using livy for spark. Not sure if it has anything to do with it.

Comment: Well, you definitely miss some Spring classes for some reason. Essentially what happens is Ignite tries to parse XML configuration and uses `ignite-spring` module for this which in turn depends on Spring JARs. Are you sure you add the whole `ignite-spring` Maven dependency, but no the `ignite-spring.jar` only without Spring JARs it depends on?